# Flutter How to save Image file to Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I want to save the image file captured to Firebase Realtime Database and I cannot seem to get it right. May anyone please help.
My code is below:

```
class TakePictureScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  List<BarcodeItem> value;


  TakePictureScreen({Key? key, required this.value,}) : super(key: key);

  //final String title;

  @override
  _TakePictureScreenState createState() => _TakePictureScreenState();
}

class _TakePictureScreenState extends State<TakePictureScreen> {
  final photos = <File>[];
  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final firestoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final DatabaseReference databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('ScannedResults');

  void openCamera() {
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => CameraCamera(
              onFile: (file) {
                photos.add(file);
                Navigator.pop(context);
                setState(() {});
              },
            )));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Capture Image"),
      ),

      body: GridView.builder(
        gridDelegate:
        SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
        itemCount: photos.length,
        itemBuilder: (_, index) => Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),

          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Wrap(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: size.width,

                  child: Image.file(
                    photos[index],
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),

                ),
                Container(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: ListView.builder(

                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: widget.value.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                        return Text(widget.value[position].text.toString().split('%').toString());

                      },

                    ),

                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: FlatButton(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    child: Text('Save',),
                    onPressed: () {

                      databaseRef.push().set({
                        'ScannedItem': photos
                            .map((barCodeItem) => barCodeItem)
                            .toList(),
                      });

                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),

        ),

      ),

      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: openCamera,
        child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
      ),


    );
  }
}
```

I am saving using button click 'Save', may you please show me what am I doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated. Also if anyone knows also how I can save the data returned in the lisview together with the image file, I will also appreciate that a lot

Answer (score 1):

You basically cannot store files in Realtime Database. You'll have to upload the images/files to Firebase Cloud Storage or any other storage provider as per your preference first and then save the returned URLs to the DB (Realtime Database in this case).

Here's FlutterFire docs for Firebase Cloud Storage: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage

So basically the pseudo code will look something like this:

```
List<String> imageURLs = [];
final fss = FirebaseStorageService();
await fss.uploadImagesToCloudStorage().then((List urls) => imageURLs = urls);
```

Where `FirebaseStorageService` will be a custom service class for Firebase Cloud Storage.